# A PhD from a lower-ranked university or a PhD from a higher-ranked university with less-known and less cited supervisor?

Tags: education

Which is better, a PhD from a lower-ranked university with a well-known and highly cited supervisor, or a PhD from a higher-ranked university with less-known and less cited supervisor?

**Note** :My subject is Mathematics (Commutative Algebra)  .

Comment: Why do you think you're going to have enough knowledge of the quality of supervisors to base a decision on it?

Comment: @Anonymous Specifically, in my case  Most assistant professors in high ranking universities are newly appointed and do not have much research experience, while some professors in low ranking universities are older and have a lot of experience

Comment: Define ‘better’?

Comment: @user438383 I mean benefits